# I can't upgrade anymore because of unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I can't upgrade.When I try I get:

```
user1@NC210:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libfreetype6 : Breaks: libfreetype6:i386 (!= 2.4.8-1ubuntu2.4) but 2.4.8-1ubuntu2.5 is installed
 libfreetype6:i386 : Breaks: libfreetype6 (!= 2.4.8-1ubuntu2.5) but 2.4.8-1ubuntu2.4 is installed
 libxslt1.1 : Breaks: libxslt1.1:i386 (!= 1.1.26-8ubuntu1.3) but 1.1.26-8ubuntu1.4 is installed
 libxslt1.1:i386 : Breaks: libxslt1.1 (!= 1.1.26-8ubuntu1.4) but 1.1.26-8ubuntu1.3 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

And when I do next 'apt-get -f install' I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libfreetype6 libxslt1.1
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libfreetype6 libxslt1.1
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/512 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
dpkg: error processing libfreetype6 (--configure):
 libfreetype6:amd64 2.4.8-1ubuntu2.4 cannot be configured because libfreetype6:i386 is in a different version (2.4.8-1ubuntu2.5)
dpkg: error processing libfreetype6:i386 (--configure):
 libfreetype6:i386 2.4.8-1ubuntu2.5 cannot be configured because libfreetype6:amd64 is in a different version (2.4.8-1ubuntu2.4)
dpkg: error processing libxslt1.1 (--configure):
 libxslt1.1:amd64 1.1.26-8ubuntu1.3 cannot be configured because libxslt1.1:i386 is in a different version (1.1.26-8ubuntu1.4)
dpkg: error processing libxslt1.1:i386 (--configure):
 libxslt1.1:i386 1.1.26-8ubuntu1.4 cannot be configured because libxslt1.1:amd64 is in a different version (1.1.26-8ubuntu1.3)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libfreetype6
 libfreetype6:i386
 libxslt1.1
 libxslt1.1:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am new to ubuntu and I have been trying to solve this problem for days so any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: You seem to have unwisely instructed your system install a package that is *incompatible* with your current version of Ubuntu. What were you trying to install? Whatever it was, remove it. Whatever source it was from, delete that source - it is not your friend.

Comment: It is the result of an upgrade which could not be completed and not of the installation of a specific package.

Comment: Daily apt upgrade? Release-upgrade to a different release of Ubuntu? Something else? What was the exact reason given for the failure?

Comment: Actually, the libfreetype6 problem occured first. Until yesterday that was the only issue. It is  the result of a daily apt upgrade that froze. The libxslt1.1 problem emerged yesterday while trying to solve the first issue through a dist-upgrade

Comment: The dist-upgrade could not go through successfully and I ended up with a second package with an inconsistency. I have tried to upgrade the two packages through apt without success. I have also tried to remove them the same way in order to reinstall them, but due to too many  dependencies the system wouldn't let me.

Comment: If you are 'new to Ubuntu', why did you install 5-year old Ubuntu 12.04 that is already EOL and out of support? A wise course would be to backup your data, then install a supported version of Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm not the one who installed the OS, I inherited it with the computer. If everything else fails  I will definitely follow the course of action you suggest.